# How do I manipulate the axis of a svg chart?

Tags: d3.js, svg, epoch.js

I am drawing a scatter chart using d3.js and epoch. The values that becomes the circles in the chart are based on log values, which makes my both axis go below zero.

```
 var chart = $('#scatterchart').epoch({ type: 'scatter', data: scatterData, axes: ['bottom', 'left'], ticks: { right: 4, bottom: 4}, domain: [-1.4, 2], range: [-2,4], margins: { top: 10, right: 80, bottom: 60, left: 80 }, });
```

I would like to keep the position of the circles but manipulate the axis so that:

```
x(horisontal):
-1 -> 0.5
0 -> 1
1 -> 2
2 -> 4

y(vertical):
-2 -> 0.25
-1 -> 0.5
0 -> 1
1 -> 2
2 -> 4
3 -> 8
4 -> 16
```

Anyone that has any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean replace the tick labels (-1 becomes .5, 0 becomes 1,...) ?

Comment: @Anna this would be very easy with d3 only: `var myScale = d3.scalePow().exponent(2)`. However, according to Epoch documentation, it seems that you cannot set the type of the d3 scale.

Comment: @GuitarExtended, exactly like so. Now I am hiding the curent labels so that the circels appear to end up right on the graph and I want to find a way to translate the label values from -1 to 0.5 etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with epoch.js, and I don't know if you can tweak the axes it creates.
But you could try to transform your data before feeding it to your scatterplot generator.

If scatterData is an array, you could use array.map():

```
newData = scatterData.map(function(d){return someTransformFuntion(d);});
```

And adapt the input domain of your axis (actually, your scale) accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

I have no experience with epoch.

But assuming it works on top of d3js, all you need to do is change the domain of both of your scales.

When you visualise your data, you work with a domain (for data) and a range (pixels on your screen). So to support negative values, you would need to adjust the domain to support [-2, 4] (for the y axis example).

As a bonus some reading about [domains](http://www.jeromecukier.net/blog/2011/08/11/d3-scales-and-color/) and [negative values](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2368837)